# 2d game rotation interpolation over network

Tags: networking, rotation, 2d, interpolation

I am working on a simple 2d multiplayer game with players that have a turret that faces a certain direction (0-360 degrees)

The turret is slow at changing its direction and thus has two values:

- heading, which is the direction it is currently facing
- desiredHeading, which is the direction it wants to face (player input)

The function moveTurret() is called once per frame and increases/decreases the heading by a certain value, so it matches the desiredHeading after some time. (--> turret moves slowly into desired direction)

Since my client receives updates every X milliseconds via the network, I have a hard time to render those rotations smoothly!

My current approach is as follows:

- client periodically receives the heading for each other player
- client sets the received values as desiredHeading for the respective players
- moveTurret() is called for those players every frame

I thought the client would then approximate the rotation and would smoothly render the turret into its right direction, however this doesn't work at all and the animation is wobbling back and forth.

Does anyone know a simple approach for this problem? I have found some quaternion interpolation and matrix based algorithms, but none seemed to fit for my approach, since I only have a heading-value and my game does not use matrix calculations.

Comment: So they get the heading from the other players?
Why not send the desiredHeading instead, and moving the turrets on the clientside? Isn't that more relevant?

Comment: you are right i guess! thanks for the hint, i will try that.